# Uncaught Reference Error: Gmaps.js error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the gmaps plugin. I've followed the example given and even looked at the page source and copied it, yet I still have no progress.

This is my chunk of html with js files included.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>testss</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/maps.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Convergence|Bitter|Droid+Sans|Ubuntu+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var map = new GMaps({
div: '#map', lat: -12, lng: -77
  });
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting these errors:

Uncaught Google Maps API is required. Please register the following JavaScript library
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true. maps.js:22

Uncaught ReferenceError: GMaps is not defined

Not sure why this issue is appearing since I've included the file. Any ideas are much appreciated!

If this helps, I'm using node.js and express on localhost.

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: Ah thanks, found something strange

Comment: What is "/javascripts/maps.js"?  If it requires the Google Maps Javascript API v3, you need to include that first.

Comment: Include <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script> before gmap.js

Comment: hi, dd u sove this error? I am stuck with exact same error now.

Answer (score 1):

That's a dependency error. Include http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js **before** your call to /javascript/gmaps.js

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the registration url of google maps api. Please use `https` instead of `http`.
Include this url:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, who was using the wrong documentation your or I, but this seems to be working quite fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>testss</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/maps.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Convergence|Bitter|Droid+Sans|Ubuntu+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'), 
        {
          zoom: 15,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-12, -77)
        }
      );
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="height: 20em;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**edit:** I just realized you were trying to use [gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) - but in that case you're missing the gmaps.js file unless that is what your maps.js was for.

You can download the current version at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HPNeo/gmaps/master/gmaps.js

Comment: Yea, I was using gmaps.js but it seems there's some unallowed API usage.